# Is using "me too" inclusive of multiple items in a list?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Take the following discussion:

> A: I want to go to Japan and Australia.
> B: Me too.

Would B's statement "me too" be referring to both countries or only one?

Answer (score 1):

The response could refer to either statement or both, but quite probably both, as the responder would be likely to indicate disagreement with either individual part. But with this kind of casual speech, one cannot be sure. In person tone of voice and context might make the meaning clearer.